# How can I check whether a 10k digit integer is a probable prime?

Tags: prime-numbers

I would like to detect prime numbers within an interval $\mathcal{I}:[a,b]$. The only problem is that the interval contains very large numbers - in excess of 10000 digits each and $\# \mathcal{I}$ is also very large.

One of my tasks involves answering the following question:

"*Given a positive integer $i\in\mathcal I$, is $i$ prime?*"

Testing for primality using `PrimeQ[]` takes far too long for this many large numbers. So, I thought about first gathering a list of probable primes, before engaging in any rigorous prime-proving process.

So basically what I'm asking is whether there exists a function like `ProbablePrimeQ[]` that can  return very fast and give a first indication whether the input is prime. Does such a function exist in Mathematica?

Comment: `PrimeQ` is already the fast probabilistic primality test. It combines small prime testing, Miller-Rabin testing in base 2 & 3 and a Lucas Test. This procedure is known to produce no false positive for $<2^{64}$. Mathematica features a provable prime test `ProvablePrimeQ` (in the primality proving package `<<PrimalityProving`) which is much slower than `PrimeQ`. If you need to generate a list of good candidates, just do your own small prime tests beforehand with the first few thousand primes or so. This should be reasonable fast.

Comment: Timings for numbers with 10K digits are not too bad. Around 9 seconds per number in many of the slow cases, below milliseconds on most cases, `TableForm @ Map[
    AbsoluteTiming[PrimeQ[#]]&
    , (Round[Pi*10^11111, 2] + 1 + 2*Range[25] )
]`

Comment: @JulienKluge Thanks. Do you know some "standard" way of doing that in Mathematica? Do you perhaps have a link to an existing SE post? Or do you just mean "divide by the first thousand primes"?

Comment: @rhermans If we take 4.5 seconds per call to `PrimeQ[]`, and assuming I have to check $10^9$ numbers in the interval, I would require 142 years to complete the task. If I go through $10^{10}$ numbers, then that changes to 1425 years. I don't think I can wait that long.

Comment: @Klangen it is not about your expectations, but about what Mathematica can do. You were already told that `ProvablePrimeQ` is slower than `PrimeQ`. Unless you present a more constrained case with a clever idea to be implemented, this is as far one can go with your general question.

Comment: If I recall correctly the slower step in `PrimeQ`, when assessing numbers that are in fact prime, is the use of the Lucas test. So you might just implement Miller-Rabin for a couple of bases. But there might then be a handful of composites that are claimed as prime.